# Heroku Certs on custom domain not working

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I'm running a hobby plan on Heroku and i am struggeling to secure the connection to my custom domain.

I enabled the ACM by `heroku certs:auto:enable -a <app name>` and checked the status with `heroku certs:auto`. The Status is saying "*Cert Issued*", so from [Herokus Description](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) "*A certificate has been issued for the domain.*"

But when i go to my custom domain it is still not secure. In my opinion the Error has to do something with the DNS-Target because of Heroku saying:

> When you enable ACM, ensure that your DNS is pointed at its new DNS target. If it’s pointed at *.herokuapp.com or *.herokussl.com, Heroku is unable to verify your certificate. Run `heroku domains` to verify the DNS target.

But if i look at the DNS-Targets of my custom domains (`heroku domains`) the DNS-Target is absoluetely the same, looking like `somerandomwordsandnumbers.herokudns.com`

I appreciate some help, thx

Comment: Hello, did you fix it? I'am struggling with the exact same problem.

Comment: Hey @kislay Kunal, this was some time ago, but i have made a Support ticket in heroku for this. Therefore i'll share the conversation with me and the support within the next few days ;)